# google maps flagging as an input type android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-inputtype

I was wondering if I can capture user input in google maps. For example if I click the map there will be a mark/flag and if click my save button the mark/flag will be saved in my database?

Comment: You're going to have to do some research into the Google Maps API.  Then come back here and ask how to improve what you've learned.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, and requests for tutorials are off-topic, so I removed that part of your post. I was going to give you links to some other SO posts, however I didn't find any real canonical answer for this. So, I went ahead and posted an answer regarding the map portion of your question.  As for the database functionality, there are plenty of other posts on SO that can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a map click listener, and place a Marker on the point that the user has tapped:

```
 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            //save current location
            latLng = point;

            //remove previously placed Marker
            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }

            //place marker where user just clicked
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

        }
    });
```

Then you can add a button, and in the button click listener you would have your code that saves the data from the current Marker to your database.

Full class code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Button saveButton;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private Marker marker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //check of user has placed a marker
                if (latLng != null){
                    double lat = latLng.latitude;
                    double lon = latLng.longitude;
                    //save location data in database
                    //...................

                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location Saved: " + lat + " " + lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                //save current location
                latLng = point;

                //remove previously placed Marker
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                //place marker where user just clicked
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:text="Save Current Marker Position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result after tapping the map to place a Marker, and then clicking the Save button:

[image]